# Visual Studios C# - Changed file directories, deleted .suo and now certain functions do not work

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio

I have been coding a function to interface call MATLAB functions in C#. Everything was working fine until I noticed that even after updating my MATLAB functions, the C# seemed to be calling the old functions. So I decide to delete the .suo file and in the mean time I also reorganized my folder structure.

Now in my C#, I cannot seem to call one of the C# functions to call the MATLAB code. Specifically I am getting the error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

    Additional information: Error using cd

    Too many input arguments.
```

On this line of code:

```
        matlab.Feval("FFTAnalysis", 1, out result, fileNamesToAnalyzeText.Text, Convert.ToDouble(N));
```

Does anyone know what the issue is? Here is the C#

```
private void matlabFFT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int N = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfFilesText.Text);

    // Create the MATLAB instance 
    MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

    // Change to the directory where the function is located 
    matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\Users\Justin\OneDrive\Courses\MECH 423\Final Project\8_MATLAB_FFTAnalysis");

    // Define the output 
    object result = null;

    // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
    //matlab.Feval("FFTAnalysis", 2, out result, fileNamesToAnalyzeText.Text, Convert.ToDouble(N));
    matlab.Feval("FFTAnalysis", 1, out result, fileNamesToAnalyzeText.Text, Convert.ToDouble(N));

    // Quit MATLAB
}
```

And the MATLAB code:

```
function [frequency] = FFTAnalysis(fileName, N)
    close all
    N = double(N);

    % Change the current folder to the folder of this m-file.
    % Courtesy of Brett Shoelson
    if(~isdeployed)
      cd(fileparts(which(mfilename)));
    end
    dir = 'C:\Users\Justin\OneDrive\Courses\MECH 423\Final Project\5_C_Sharp_Egg_Test_Data_Logger\Data_Log_Files\';

    Fs = 111.9;           % Sampling frequency
    T = 1/Fs;

    data = cell(1,N);

    for i=1:N;
    %     fileName = 'DATA_3MIN_3_';
        postfix = '.txt';
        fullFileName = strcat({dir},{'\'},{fileName},{int2str(i)},{postfix});
        data{i} = load(fullFileName{1});

        average = mean(data{i});
        indices = find(abs(data{i})>1000);
        data{i}(indices) = average;

        [b,a] = butter(4,[5/(Fs/2) 12/(Fs/2)]);
        data{i} = filtfilt(b,a,data{i});

        L = length(data{i});

        Y = fft(data{i});
        P2 = abs(Y/L);
        P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
        P1(1) = 0;
        P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
        f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
        t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector

        [m,n] = max(P1);
        frequency = n*(Fs/L);

        subplot(2,N,i);
        plot(t,data{i});
        textFile = strcat({AppendBackslash(fileName)},{int2str(i)},{postfix});
        title({'Raw Signal for ';textFile{1}});

        subplot(2,N,i+N);
        plot(f,P1);
        peakFreq = strcat({'Egg Frequency: '},{num2str(frequency)});
        title({'Frequency Histogram';num2str(frequency)});
    end
end

function [outStr] = AppendBackslash(tStr) 
    special = '_';

    outStr = '';
    for l = tStr
        if (length(find(special == l)) > 0)
            outStr = [outStr, '\', l];
        else
            outStr = [outStr, l];
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hint in your error message:

> > Additional information: Error using cd
> >
> > Too many input arguments.

If you're going to `cd` to a path that has spaces, you have to wrap the path in quotes, or else it thinks you're trying to pass it separate arguments split on spaces.

You can escape quotes (and other characters) by using "\", but of course now you need to make sure that the "\" you use in the path are valid.

Try

```
matlab.Execute("cd \"c:\\Users\\Justin\\OneDrive\\Courses\\MECH 423\\Final Project\\8_MATLAB_FFTAnalysis\"");
```

You'll also need to do the same with your filename that you pass into the matlab function, it looks like that's `fileNamesToAnalyzeText.Text`.